# jquery - write error outside closing div that contains input targetted by name

Tags: jquery, html

I have researched this but can't find an answer.

I have a form which contains a number of inputs. For simplicity let's say there are only two called "Field 1" and "Field 2". Markup is as follows - very straightforward:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Field 1</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="field1" class="form-control" id="field-1">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Field 2</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="field2" class="form-control" id="field-2">
    </div>
</div>
```

I am making an ajax request, and if there is an error, writing the error message using the following jquery:

```
var msg = '<span class="help-block">Error message string</span>';
$('input[name="' + i + '"]').after(msg);
$('input[name="' + i + '"]').closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
```

In the above example, `i`, represents the `name` attribute on the form. So if the error was on `field1` the markup generated would be:

```
<div class="form-group has-error">
    <label>Field 1</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="field1" class="form-control" id="field-1">
        <span class="help-block">Error message string</span> 
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem I'm having is that I need the error message to appear *after* the closing `.input-group` as opposed to inside it. So I need it like this:

```
<div class="form-group has-error">
    <label>Field 1</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="field1" class="form-control" id="field-1">
    </div>
    <!-- Note: appears after closing .input-group div -->
    <span class="help-block">Error message string</span>   
</div>
```

I'm not sure how to target this with jquery? Because there are multiple inputs they still need to be targetted based on the `name` attribute of the field (e.g. `field1`, `field2`, etc). But they need to appear after the closing `</div>` for the `.input-group` that contains it.

Is this possible?

jquery 3.2.1

Comment: try $('input[name="' + i + '"]').parent().after(msg);

Comment: @NawazGhori yes, that works, thank you. If you post it as an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: `.parent()` works only if the .input-group divs are guaranteed to be the immediate parents of the inputs, otherwise just use closest('.input-group') as you are already doing for the has-error class (see my answer)

Comment: @pschichtel as the given HTML has an immediate parent of .input-group I have used parent(). (Answer as per the given HTML)

Comment: Considering `closest('.form-group')` is already being used in the original code snippet I expected there to be a reason for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change  `$('input[name="' + i + '"]').after(msg);` to

`$('input[name="' + i + '"]').parent().after(msg);`

You can get more details on  [.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/). Targetting  completely depends on your HTML code you write

Answer (score 1):

You already have your solution: instead of `$('input[name="' + i + '"]')` use `$('input[name="' + i + '"]').closest('.input-group')` when applying `.after()`:

Your code rewritten:

```
var msg = '<span class="help-block">Error message string</span>';
$('input[name="' + i + '"]').closest('.form-group')
    .addClass('has-error')
    .after(msg);
```